# Windows Vista C: drive full - how to clear - what to clear?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-vista, disk-space, user-management

My C: drive is full and I need to clear some space. I'm running Windows Vista.

Below is my disk space break down for my C: drive:

[image]

Which files can I safely delete?

Below is the break down for my Windows folder:

[image]

Comment: You have a 37 GB hard drive. There is VERY little you can do to prevent that from filling up in a hurry. Probably your best bet is a bigger drive.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to gain lots of space is to clean old restore points - but this also means you will have only the most recent restore point. To do this go to properties of drive C, select disk clean up. In disk cleanup select "Clean up system files" you will then have a tab that you can access to clean up restore points. This will clean all but the most recent restore point and can gain back lots of space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need larger storage HD. 39 GB is quite little.

[Uninstall](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) unused Application.

[Clean](http://www.ccleaner.com/) temp files, caches on the disk.

Use [portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/). They can run other partitions like D: or USB sticks.

Comment: You can install non-portable applications anywhere you like, too.